# how to get lat and lon of a checkin in Foursquare?

Tags: java, foursquare, checkin

There are many 4sq checkin tweets posted on Twitter. These tweets all contain a link to foursquare.com.

The link, for example, https://foursquare.com/donnyndra/checkin/4f60500ae4b02a8707007b93?s=ogf_jvcuoha1T0QUfIRVWGupvuc&ref=tw, has a checkin id and a signature.

The question is how can I obtain the lat and lon of the checkin by using the checkin id and signature?

I use Java language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an API request to get checkin details: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins

In the response is a "location" section that includes latitude/longitude.

Comment: Hi Hall, In the page you gave, it says that this API request requires Acting User. What does this mean? I want to know the id of the venue where user check in, as well as lat and lon of a checkin. Note that these checkins are made by other people, I only have client_id, client_secret, CHECKIN_ID, and signature.

Comment: It seems like that I should have a user auth my app for access. Am I right? But there are thousands of checkin tweets I collected, I can never let these foursquare users auth my app so that I have access token for ever user. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If the docs say you need an acting user, it means you will need to get the auth credentials of a user before making the request.